# How can I move tmux's status bar to the top?

Tags: tmux

How can I move tmux's status bar to the top? Can't find it on the man page.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Add `set-option -g status-position top` to `~/.tmux.conf`. (See @ChrisJohnsen's comment above)

Comment: FYI - if you're using `byobu` (which in turn uses tmux) then edit `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf`if it exists

Comment: I had to use `set-window-option` instead of `set-option` for it to work

Comment: this worked great. for some reason I expected the file to already be there, but it wasn't, so had to `touch ~/.tmux.conf` first (just in case it's unclear to someone else in the future)

Answer (score 25):

The feature request Michael Mrozek mentioned has been closed with the feature being available in the next release (1.7). The request says you can test it out now by building from SVN. If you use Homebrew on Mac OS X you could (theoretically) just do `brew upgrade --HEAD tmux`. Unfortunately I upgrade to Xcode 4.3 which seems to be missing autoconf/automake.

Comment: This is how it would look in `~/.tmux.conf`: `set-option -g status-position top` (the default is `bottom`).