# tmux: how can one position the status bar at true bottom?

Tags: tmux

Fairly new to tmux, and have been gradually adding stuff to my config file.

I have the line `set -g status-position bottom` to put my status bar at the bottom, but there is still a large amount of clearance at the bottom of the frame.
[image]

I would like the bar to be flush with the bottom of the screen.

[This was the only other SE question I could find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15316/how-can-i-move-tmuxs-status-bar-to-the-top?newreg=6ad3230ad0d84e8c913e4e0b42c30bcc), and tmux's Github issues didn't seem to have anything.  The man page has only top and bottom as options for `status-position`, and no other relevant options I could find.

Any dot file dynamos got any recommendations?

Comment: Hack the source; it is not configurable.

Comment: Does your terminal emulator lock the display height to full rows of display, or does it allow smooth resizing? tmux usually displays on the lower full row of terminal output, which might not coincide with the bottom of a pseudo-terminal.

Comment: __jasonwryan__ maybe if I don't find a solution you'll see a pull request in a few months (:

Comment: __datUser__ not entirely sure what you mean.  Using Terminator, looking around for the display height thing mentioned

Comment: Try just resizing the height a bit, some emulators do this in increments of complete rows of input. Others don't enforce that and just fudge the margins of the terminal emulator. That gap could just be a UI margin rather than any real space below the tmux bar. Just do some playing with the window size of Terminator. OR it could be a default margin inside of terminator.

Comment: Aye, found that it was a margin being enforced by Terminator, but only when using multiple tabs.  tmux is gradually reducing my reliance on such anyway, so not so much of a problem now.

Answer (score 2):

Some terminals have default padding on the sides, if you're using gnome-terminal, try adding the following to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

```css
VteTerminal,
vte-terminal,
TerminalScreen {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  -VteTerminal-inner-border: 0px;
}
```

Also, scrollbars might take up additional padding so disabling it helped in my case.

#### Related

- https://superuser.com/questions/904044/move-tmux-status-bar-to-the-very-bottom-of-my-screen
- https://superuser.com/questions/1107509/padding-in-gnome-terminal
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/115762/increase-padding-in-gnome-terminal

Comment: Additionally if each line takes exactly N pixels and the height is not divisible by N then the non-zero remainder has to go somewhere; it cannot belong to any line. In computers it's common to count from the top (top-left corner specifically), so the remainder will most likely be at the bottom.